# How to return the proper data from this function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function getUserData(name) {
var userData = {};
twitter.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json', {screen_name:name}, function(data) {
    userData = {
        name: data[0].screen_name,
        screenname: data[0].screen_name,
        id: data[0].id,
        url: data[0].url,
        description: data[0].description
    }
});
return userData;
}
```

I want to be able to write something like:

```
var userData = getUserData(name);
```

and have it return that userData object.

Comment: have you tried it yet? any attempts at debugging?  what happens right now with that code you posted?  i dont see any glaring errors, so it would help to get some more details

Comment: You are misunderstanding the nature of asynchronous programming.  The function does not have the data when it returns.  The callback is executed later when the data becomes is returned from the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

AJAX calls are *asynchronous*. You need to use callbacks in some manner or another.

```
function getUserData(name, cb) {
    var userData = {};
    twitter.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json', {
        screen_name: name
    }, function(data) {
        userData = {
            name: data[0].screen_name,
            screenname: data[0].screen_name,
            id: data[0].id,
            url: data[0].url,
            description: data[0].description
        }
        cb(userData);
    });
}

getUserData(name, function(userData) {
    // do stuff.
});
```

If your using jQuery 1.5 you can use deferred promises which are [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects.

```
function getUserData(name, cb) {
    var def = new jQuery.Deferred();
    twitter.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json', {
        screen_name: name
    }, function(data) {
        var userData = {
            name: data[0].screen_name,
            screenname: data[0].screen_name,
            id: data[0].id,
            url: data[0].url,
            description: data[0].description
        }
        def.resolve(userData);
    });
    return def.promise();
}

var promise = getUserData(name);
promise.done(function(data) {
     // do stuff.
});
```

Comment: @float there is an option to make a synchronous ajax call but that's really bad. This should be avoided at all costs, passing callbacks or promises around is preferable in all cases. Synchronous ajax is only viable when dealing with large code bases and re-factoring is not cost effective.

Comment: I'm running into a strange error:

`userData.name should = "THE CORRECT NAME"

.../server.js:470
  sys.puts('userData.name should = '+JSON.stringify(data[0].name));
                                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: The system puts the correct value in the console but then also throws an error that it is undefined - any ideas?

Comment: @float sorry you can't use `userData` I didn't remove that. You need to access `userData` inside the callback function. Take another look at the example.